# Deleting a folder with a missing checked out file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error

I need to delete a folder that does not have any file in it. However it always moves me to an error page, that the folder is checked out to someone. I tried opening it on the Sharepoint designer but still can't delete it. As the file is no were to be found and the user is not stated. Please see below for the error message. How can I delete this?

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file is already checked out by any other user than you will not able to see that file in your folder(for the current version only). Please check-in that file first than after you can process further.

If it is still not working than

Please delete all files from `RecycleBin` folder from site & site collection first then after please try to delete the folder.